# C# regex for regular expression

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split string into 3 parts.
E.g.:

```
text = "(123-12)selis(qard)";  
into 
string1 = 123-12
string2 = selis
string3 = gard
```

Thank you!.

Comment: Based on what? The round brackets?

Comment: you really should show / display more effort

Comment: To use e regex, you need to know more about the content of the text that you have. For example: Are there possibly more braces? Which parts change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split string does this really easily...

```
 var strings =text.Split(new [] { '(', ')'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var string1 = strings[0];
 var string2 = strings[1];
 var string3 = strings[2];
```

and if you really want regex

```
var regex = new Regex("[(|)]",  RegexOptions.Compiled  );
var strings = regex.Split("(123-12)selis(qard)").Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```

Comment: You appear to have one too many `)` at the end of your coded answer

Comment: ta, removed...need a syntax checker :)

Comment: lol I always test the code that I put on here as an answer lol

Answer (score 0):

here is a fully coded example so that it will make sense to you

```
var text = "(123-12)selis(qard)";
var splitString = text.Split(new char[] {'(', ')'},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```